# How to get the groups that a contact belongs to?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, abaddressbook

How can I get a an array of parent `ABGroups` for an `ABPerson` in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you cannot. The [ABPersonCopyParentGroups](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABPersonRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyParentGroups) API is only documented for OSX (web site and header files) and a bit of testing shows it is not [available](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4724) on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you do it the same way you do in Obj-C, using [ABPersonCopyParentGroups](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABPersonRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyParentGroups).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973510/find-which-abpersons-group-abgroup-in-ios4

Comment: I don't see that method in the MonoTouch classes, strangely. Maybe this has not been implemented?

Comment: if that's the case, you should file a bug with Xamarin